# UML new lifeline

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I am doing a UML sequence diagram and I've got like, say, a GUI Controller object who wants to create a new Circle object and then add it to an ActiveDrawables object. Would the diagram in the picture below be correct? Or should I've sent the `add()` from like the Circle's lifeline (thought this seems kind of weird)?

[image]

In code, for example, the Controller would have been the one calling `add`, like in the picture, but I was having doubts whether I should have sent the message from the Circle's lifeline (though, again, this seems weird).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it depends on your design, but what you have drawn is the usual approach.

The other approach (with `Circle` contacting `ActiveDrawables`) is sometimes used as well, e.g.

- when all `Circles` has to be in the same `ActiveDrawables`,
- for efficiency reasons `GUIController` might pass `ActiveDrawables` identifier to `Circle` to create it immediately in `ActiveDrawables`
- if `Circle` needs to be always attached to `ActiveDrawables` you may also pass identifier like in previous point

Few things to consider about your diagram:

1. You don't have to number your messages. It's a technology used in communication diagram rather than in sequence diagram.
2. The last message seems to be a return (reply) from the previous one. You should use a different arrow for that.
3. Instead of `Circle` name the lifeline `c1: Circle`. Then you'll have an object `c1` of type `Circle`. Then in `add` operation you can use `c1` showing precisely that your passing the newly created `Circle` object, not just some `Circle`.

Comment: Re. 2.:instead of "different ..." write "dashed line  to indicate a return". Re. 3: Though the `:`-notation is more clear, it's not uncommon to write object names without the `:` in life lines (see specs: p. 570)

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help :). I unerstand. The numbering of the messages is actually something Visual Paradigm (the tool I used to draw the diagram) seems to be adding by default.. I'll try to remove them.

Comment: @PhantomR It won't be wrong with he numbering. It's just superfluous. Can't help with VP but there will probably be some setting.

Comment: @Thomas Kilian: I understand :). Indeed, there is actually a setting, thank you. If anyone else using Visual Paradigm reads this, you can hide the numbers by right clicking the background, and then selecting Presentation Options -> Message Display Options -> [uncheck] Show Sequence Numbers.

Comment: Re. 2: I don't think the last arrow is a reply message. UpdateGUI does not sound like a return value, but like ActiveDrawables is really making a separate call to Controller.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl OK, you might be right (well, I said only it seems to be a return ;-) ). But in this case execution specification would be messed up. Either there should be an overlapping execution specification on Controller when the updateGUI is received or there should be two separated execution specification - one that ends somewhere after sending add and the second one starting at receiving updateGUI.

Comment: Yes, the overlapping execution bar is missing.